# Pandas GroupBy to Aggregate Values into Dictionary with Keys from one column and Values based on another column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dictionary, group-by, lookup

I'm trying to create an "aggregated" dictionary/JSON-like object inside a cell of a DataFrame where the keys are the values according to another column (for a particular group). Will illustrate this with an example below.

To begin, I'm starting with an table I've already called `.explode` on.

***Starting Table: `start_df`***

| child_id | parent_id | parent_name | tag_id | tag_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 100 | 'Zack' | 99 | 'Builder' |
| 12345 | 101 | 'Cody' | 67 | 'Plumber' |
| 12345 | 102 | 'Jill' | 43 | 'Doctor' |
| 12345 | 102 | 'Jill' | 47 | 'Harvard' |
| 67890 | 108 | 'Emily' | 31 | 'Artist' |
| 67890 | 102 | 'Jill' | 43 | 'Doctor' |
| 67890 | 102 | 'Jill' | 47 | 'Harvard' |

For context, parents contain tags (properties) that a child will inherit. My goal is to create

***Goal Table: `output_df`***

| child_id | parent_id_list | parent_desc_dict | full_tag_id_list | tag_ancestry |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | [100, 101, 102] | {100: 'Zack', 101: 'Cody', 102: 'Jill' } | [99, 67, 43, 47] | {100: [99], 101: [67], 102: [43, 47] } |
| 67890 | [102, 108] | {102: 'Jill', 108: 'Emily' } | [43, 47, 31] | {102: [43, 47], 108: [31] } |

---

For the lists `parent_id_list` and `full_tag_id_list`, I [learned from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73031553/concatenating-lists-across-different-rows-within-a-dataframe-according-to-anothe) that we can do something like

```py
start_df.groupby([collection_id], as_index = False).agg({'parent_id': list, 'tag_id': list})
```

...but how do we generate the dictionaries `parent_desc_dict` and `tag_ancestry`? Simply replacing `list` with `dict` won't do the job since that takes the row number as the dictionary's Key instead of the `parent_id`. I figured the way to do this is with lambda functions somehow but not sure how to integrate it with the `.agg`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let us use custom `agg` func with `groupby + apply`:

```
def agg(g):
    return pd.Series({
        'parent_id_list': [*g['parent_id'].unique()],
        'parent_desc_dict': dict(zip(g['parent_id'], g['parent_name'])),
        'full_tag_id_list': [*g['tag_id']],
        'tag_ancestry': g.groupby('parent_id')['tag_id'].agg(list).to_dict()
    })


df.groupby('child_id').apply(agg)
```

---

```
           parent_id_list                        parent_desc_dict  full_tag_id_list                           tag_ancestry
child_id                                                                                                                         
12345     [100, 101, 102]  {100: 'Zack', 101: 'Cody', 102: 'Jill'}  [99, 67, 43, 47]  {100: [99], 101: [67], 102: [43, 47]}
67890          [108, 102]              {108: 'Emily', 102: 'Jill'}      [31, 43, 47]             {102: [43, 47], 108: [31]}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you! Would you mind elaborating on what the * in front of the dataframe is doing? I've never seen this before and can't seem to find official documentation on this syntax

Comment: @quant_fin `*` is an unpacking operator which is used here to unpack series to list..here it is essentially same as using `list(g['tag_id'])` instead of `[*g['tag_id']]`